# Angularjs:Remove duplicate property, but get our value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Output of console.log() is given below. I want to remove duplicate "characteristic", but get our "value".

This is my foreach for make result from below code:

```
angular.forEach(checkCharacteristicValue, function(item) {
  console.log(item)
  $scope.allCharAndValue.push({
    characteristic: item.businessassetcharacteristic.characteristicName,
    value: item.characteristicValue
  });
});
```

Output:

```
Object 1:
characteristic:    "Вид Маса"
value:    "2-ни"
__proto__:    Object
Object 2:
characteristic:    "Вид Маса"
value:    "4-ни"
__proto__:    Object
Object 3:
characteristic:    "Вид Маса"
value:    "6-ни"
__proto__:    Object
```

I want to see this result:`{ name:Вид Маса, value:["2-ни", "4-ни", "6-ци"] }`

Comment: I think what you meant is the result to look like this: `[{name:Вид Маса,value: ["2-ни","4-ни","6-ци"]}]`. You have shown `,` separated strings assigned to value which is incorrect

Comment: @AdityaSingh Square brackets are just on the inside, not outside.

Comment: What do you mean by `on the inside, not outside.`?

Comment: Outside will mean array of objects. Inside will mean array of values.

Comment: Could we stop with the trivial edits please?

Comment: I want on the inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i'll do it.

I use an object to store the same characteristic items and create an array with all the values for that key. Try it and tell me if it is ok for you ;)

```
var raw = [{
  characteristic:    "Вид Маса",
  value:    "2-ни"
},
{
characteristic:    "Вид Маса",
value:    "4-ни"
},
{
characteristic:    "Вид Маса",
value:    "6-ни"
}];

// dedup 
var dedup = {};
raw.forEach(function(e,i) {
  if (! dedup.hasOwnProperty(e.characteristic) ) {
        dedup[e.characteristic] = { name : e.characteristic };
        dedup[e.characteristic].value = [];
  }
  dedup[e.characteristic].value.push(e.value);
});

// flatten to fit requirements
var flatten = [];
for(var key in dedup) {
  flatten.push(dedup[key]);
}

console.log(flatten);
```

Comment: Hey i  have small problems:                                                                     Вид Маса:Array[3]
0:"2-ни"
1:"4-ни"
2:"6-ци"                                                                                                         I want see  name:Вид Маса,value:Array[3]
0:"2-ни"
1:"4-ни"
2:"6-ци"

Comment: I edit the answer, you now have somethink like that `[ { name: 'Вид Маса', value: [ '2-ни', '4-ни', '6-ни' ] } ]`

Comment: take care, i'll fix this line too `var dedup = {};` in first version, `dedup` was declared global! :-p